# Realm shows error that cannot find symbol class JsonReader Error in the proxy class

Tags: realm

Realm shows errors below when running the app.

Error:(4, 20) error: package android.util does not exist
Error:(165, 89) error: cannot find symbol class JsonReader
Error:(4, 20) error: package android.util does not exist
Error:(165, 89) error: cannot find symbol class JsonReader

When I right click the log and jump to source, it switches to the import android.util.JsonReader line in the  proxy class that Realm creates for each RealmObject.

Please help fix. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error and was caused because I was using Realm in a  "Java Library" Module.

So if you use different modules in your app, please be sure that the one that uses Realm is an Android module.

Comment: Thanks pauminku. I actually figured it out the other day. Changed the module to an Android library from Java library and it worked like a charm

Comment: Weird. You use `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` correct? I am trying to use Realm in a library module as well but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonReader` is only available from API 11, so if you call any of the `JsonReader` methods from API 9 or 10, it will crash with that exception. Realm should work fine if you don't though.

Comment: Thanks Christian. But I am actually using API 21 as the compile SDK version for all modules in my project.

Comment: Does the error happening when running the app itself or when running tests?

Comment: The error happens when I am building the project. Thanks